# Kubuntu Bounce Keys Personalization, Universal Access

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, accessibility, keys

I run kubuntu and I'm trying to make some tweaks to adapt it to my needs. I have a mechanic keyboard that has a chattering problem. In windows I was able to set the delay of bounce keys to 20ms, so everytime the keyboard would double tap, the input is registered only once.

I'm trying to do the same thing in Kubuntu but the bounce key feature allows me to set the delay to 500ms minimum, which is way above the 20ms that I need. Does someone know how to set the bounce keys to less than 500ms?
I really need it to deal with my keyboard, thank you

Comment: On GNOME you are free to set any value AFAICT. Possibly it can be done on KDE too if you figure out where the value is stored. (I'm not a Kubuntu user.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kubuntu 20.04 the minimum value achievable via `System Settings > Accessibility` is 100ms. If that's not enough you could try to set it using a command line program called `xkbset`.

I had a quick go and set a value of 20ms, but I don't have any means to test it as my keyboard doesn't have the issue you're having. I left the feature in KDE Accessibility Settings 'off' as it might otherwise interfere.

First install xkbset:

```
sudo apt install xkbset
```

Then run the command to set the bounce keys delay to 20ms:

```
xkbset bouncekeys 20
```

You can verify the current value by running:

```
xkbset q
```

and look for the following values:

```
Bounce-Keys = On
Debounce Delay = 20
```

The settings don't survive a reboot, so you could create the following (executable) script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#set-debounce-delay.sh
xkbset bouncekeys 20
```

And add it to the KDE Autostart Scripts `System Settings > Startup and Shutdown (under Workspace) > Autostart > Add script...`

Thanks to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593086).